# No routes match for custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm configuring a custom page for my user profile called profile.html.erb

I'm having a

```
No route matches {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"users"}
```

In routes, I have:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :profile
  end
end
```

My users_controller.rb

```
def profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render 'profile'
end
```

Error occurs at this line:

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_user_path %></li>
```

my rake routes

```
profile_user GET    /users/:id/profile(.:format)   users#profile
```

The profile.html.erb is working as I can access

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/profile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a member route, you need to provide the member.

`<li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_user_path(@user) %></li>`

Just doing

`<li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_user_path %></li>` without giving the user would be a route for a collection.